# Trouble w/ Certbot & Let's Encrypt on Nginx/Ubuntu14.04

Tags: nginx, lets-encrypt, certbot

I'm [following these instructions](https://certbot.eff.org/#ubuntutrusty-nginx) to install Certbot and Let's Encrypt on my DigitalOcean site running Nginx and Ubuntu 14.04, but am hitting a snag.

When I get to the alpha plugin portion: `certbot --nginx` I get the following response:

```
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
No names were found in your configuration files. Please enter in your domain
name(s) (comma and/or space separated)  (Enter 'c' to cancel):
```

I enter my domain name, hit enter and get:

```
Obtaining a new certificate
Performing the following challenges:
tls-sni-01 challenge for **MYDOMAINNAME**
Cleaning up challenges
Cannot find a VirtualHost matching domain **MYDOMAINNAME**.
```

I'm not sure how to get past this error. Here's my sites-available server block:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name localhost;

    location ~ /.well-known {
        allow all;
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location / {

        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
        # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
    }
}
```

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have server block for MYDOMAINNAME.

```
server {
server_name MYDOMAINNAME;
...
}
```

You can replace `localhost` with `MYDOMAINNAME` in the default server block at least.

Comment: Tried swapping those out in the default server block and restarting nginx, but I get the same result

Comment: What is result of `nginx -t`?

Comment: All OK. Does something need to be changed in nginx.conf? I'm only modifying the default server block in sites-available

Comment: No. Do you have access to MYDOMAINNAME with browser or curl?

Comment: Actually I added server { server_name MYDOMAINNAME; } to the http section of nginx.conf and the process worked this time. Not sure why, but it did the trick!

Answer (score 1):

Added a server block to nginx.conf and that allowed the process to finish:

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name projectapollo.io;
}
```

Comment: This also worked for me. Just to clarify, make sure that this server block is not at the root of the file but instead inside of the nginx.conf ``http`` block.